# Matlab optimisation query, avoiding that repmat

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

This is a simple question, I can't see a better answer and maybe someone else can!  Here is the code:

Example variables

```
nSim = 3000;
nRow = 10000;
data = zeros(1, 5, nRow);
data (:, 1:4, :) = rand(4, nRow)*0.5; % 4 columns of duration values
data (:, 5, :) = 1000;   % 1 column of actual value
basis.increaseRate   = 1 + (rand(nSim, 4)*0.1);
```

Example calculation

```
dataWithSim = repmat(data(:, 1:4,:),nSim, 1, 1);    
increaseFactors = bsxfun(@power, basis.increaseRate, dataWithSim);
Values = bsxfun(@times, data(:,5,:), prod(increaseFactors,2));
```

The need to repmat feels wrong, but I can't see a way to avoid it.

effectively I'm doing increase^data and I really didn't want to have to loop through the two dimensions (`sims` or `data` rows).  The dummy data can be ordered any way I choose, but the values output needs to be an `nSim` by `nRow` matrix.

Any ideas welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to use that `repmat`. You can directly feed that "submatrix" from `data` like so -

```
increaseFactors = bsxfun(@power, basis.increaseRate, data(:,1:4,:));
```

`bsxfun` internally takes care of the expansion of the `singleton` dimensions, which is the first dimension (rows) of `data` in this case. Since `basis.increaseRate` has `nSim` rows and `data(:,1,4,:)` has one row, it would be expanded to have the same number of rows, i.e. `nSim` and thus does the job of repmat-ing/expanding internally.

Rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: Of course, you don't need to have `dataWithSim` in the new code.

Comment: I swear to God I was getting endless errors about non singleton dimensions without the repmat!  Thanks - I thought I must be wrong but I just couldn't see it.

Comment: @Nt Taking care of the dimensions with `bsxfun` is really the whole play about it. It takes time for sure, but with practice you get a feel of it, soon enough! :)